# Copying Values from a loop in a table to another column - Only first 12 values (and header) pasted

Tags: excel, vba

So I am currently working with a List Object table on a piece of code - I have defined it as InTbl. What I want is to write a code that will look through the fourth column of said table (only going through the databody rows) and copying any values that may be on that row to the 9th column on the table.

For some reason, the code itself works for the first 12 rows (and the header for some reason), copying the values over fine and then stops?

Here is the code,then I'l explain where I think it has gone wrong?

```
Sub AmendMVCCY
Dim InTbl As ListObject 'Dim the input table as 'InTbl'
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, AmendedCCY As Range

Set InTbl = Sheets("Input").ListObjects("INPUT")

Set AmendedCCY = InTbl.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange


    For i = 1 To AmendedCCY.Rows.Count 'For row starting as 1 to Last row within the data body
        If Not IsEmpty(AmendedCCY.Cells(i, 1)) Then 'The the cell isn't empty
            Cells(i, 4).Copy 'Copy the figure in amended Column
            Cells(i, 9).PasteSpecial xlValues 'Paste Values in 9th Column
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

I think that when I have defined the ListColumn(4) it is misreading the data. Thw table is 200ish rows long and will only grow, but it seems that when I state 
`For i = 1 To AmendedCCY.Rows.Count`
it only counts 12 rows and not the whole lot.

It is likely this is poorly worded but I'll try and make it clearer if needs be.

Essentially, I need the loop to go through the whole Listobject table, but am not sure at to why that isn't happening atm

Edit: Picture of the table (though sample of 20 rows) [image]

Basically, in the end, I need any figures in Amended to overwrite the 9th Column (which will have monetary values in before)

Comment: Its possible to use the LastRow function to select all the values in the 4th column, then you wouldn't need to iterate through them.  Does it matter if you have blank cells?

Comment: As in copy down everything in that column?
I haven't done that as I only want to copy the cells with values, since they will be used to overwrite data in the 9th column.

If I used the LastRow function won't it copy over the empty cells too?

Comment: Just do `Cells(i, 9).value=Cells(i, 4).value` instead of the copying.  What is the `.address` of `AmendedCCY`?

Comment: You're defining `AmendedCCY` different to how you're using it. Count the rows of the table, not just the databodyrange (you're missing the count on the header to define where the last row is). When referring to cells for your `IF` statement, you're then treating `AmendedCCY` like it's the whole table, not just the databody range of one column.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, hard to tell based on what you've said so far?

Comment: What does `debug.print AmendedCCY.count` show in the immediate window?

Comment: How many cells are populated in the 4th column?

Comment: Your code is simple and it looks correct. If it does return only up to the table twelves row, we definitely look to a different table. Do you have another table on that sheet? Or are you working on the correct worksheet? Try,, please: `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count, ActiveSheet.Name, InTbl.Name`. What does it return? The 'gost' table should start with the sheet first range in order to create confusions...

Comment: Please change `Cells(i, 9).value=Cells(i, 4).value` with `InTbl.Cells(i, 9).value=InTbl.Cells(i, 4).value`. Does it still return as before this change? If not, you are on a different sheet and only it happens that the values in column 9 are the same with the desired ones...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I can't use that as the 9th column isn't in the table, but instead next to it.

Comment: But, I took it (adapted, of course) from YOUR code... You wanted to paste in `Cells(i, 9)` (from `Cells(i, 9)`... You should avoid Copy - Paste! What I suggested is the same in terms of what is to be done, but more efficient. Replying after almost one month is not something to help, anyhow...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to FanDuru's suggestion:

**Instead of:**

```
For i = 1 To AmendedCCY.Rows.Count 'For row 
    If Not IsEmpty(AmendedCCY.Cells(i, 1)) Then 'The the cell isn't empty
        Cells(i, 4).Copy 'Copy the figure in amended Column
        Cells(i, 9).PasteSpecial xlValues 'Paste Values in 9th Column
    End If
Next i
```

**Try:**

```
Dim lastRow as long
lastRow = AmendedCCY.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To lastRow 'For row starting as 1 to Last row within the data body
    If Not IsEmpty(AmendedCCY.Cells(i, 1)) Then 'The the cell isn't empty
        Cells(i, 9) = Cells(i, 4).value 
    End If
Next i
```

There's no need to use copy / paste. Make sure the table's AmendedCCY.Rows.Count is actually greater than twelve.

Comment: I am now using this code, it works okay as in it goes right to the bottom of the table, but it still doesn't copy through all the values it should. I'm not sure why it's missing lines?

Comment: are you deleting rows at all? that will cause rows to skip